# cannot recive data from model in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

i have problem with displaying data Array List<> object to JTable

```
public class SearchPatient extends JInternalFrame implements KeyListener 
{
    patientDetailBean pdb=new patientDetailBean();
    ArrayList<patientDetailBean> ap=new ArrayList<patientDetailBean>();
    String[] columnNames = {"Ptn No",
            "Name",
            "Gender",
            "City",
            "ContactNo",
            "Birth-Date",
            "MaritalStatus",
            "Occupation",
            "BloodGroup",
            "TimeOfRegistration"
            };
    DefaultTableModel dm;
    DefaultTableModel model;

    public SearchPatient()
    {
        //other initilization and displaying 

        ap=pdb.getAllPatientDetail();
        setTableData(ap);

        //other initilization, displaying and KeyListener and all working properly 
    }
    private void setTableData(ArrayList<patientDetailBean> arrayp) 
    {
        int lenap=arrayp.size();
        Object[][] data=new Object[lenap][10];      // creating dynamically array of object

        dm = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();   //creating model from table

        //removing all row from existing data in table
        while(table.getRowCount()>0) 
        { 
             ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).removeRow(0); 
        }

        //getting data from arrayp ArrayList<patientDetailBean> and save it to array of object(data)
        int in=0;
        for(Object obj:arrayp)
        {
            patientDetailBean pdb1=new patientDetailBean();
            pdb1=(patientDetailBean) obj;
            data[in][0]=pdb1.getPatientid();
            data[in][1]=pdb1.getFirstname()+" "+pdb1.getMiddlename()+" "+pdb1.getSurname();
            data[in][2]=pdb1.getGender();
            data[in][3]=pdb1.getCity();
            data[in][4]=pdb1.getContactno();
            data[in][5]=pdb1.getBirthdate();
            data[in][6]=pdb1.getMaritalstatus();
            data[in][7]=pdb1.getOccupation();
            data[in][8]=pdb1.getBloodgroup();
            data[in][9]=pdb1.getDatetimeofcase();
            in++;
        }

        //creating model from array of object(data)
        model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

        //save data to table
        table = new JTable( model );
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent key) 
    {
        //This is working proper 
        if(key.getSource().equals(txtpname))
        {
            ap=pdb.getAllPatientDetail();

            patientDetailBean pdb=new patientDetailBean();
            ArrayList<patientDetailBean> arr=new ArrayList<patientDetailBean>();
            arr.clear();
            for(Object obj:ap)
            {   
                pdb=(patientDetailBean) obj;

                //getting data from object 
                String str1=(pdb.getFirstname()+" "+pdb.getMiddlename()+" "+pdb.getSurname()).toLowerCase();

                //getting data which user entered(user want to search)  
                String str2=(txtpname.getText()+key.getKeyChar()).toLowerCase();

                if(str1.contains(str2)) // checking for data equal and contain which user typed in JTextField(txtpname) with str1
                {

                    arr.add(pdb);   //save data to ArrayList<patientDetailBean>
                }
            }

            //set recived ArrayList<> object to 
            setTableData(arr);
        }
    }

}
```

1) First time when i run this code than data got in Jtable is proper. 
   when i type any key to textField at that time the data is clearing properly from table but it is not display new data to JTable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please remove

```
table = new JTable( model );
```

and set

```
table.setModel(model);
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you're creating a new `JTable`, but you're not adding it to anything.

Take a look at [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for some examples.

You should also consider simply making a new table model and applying it the table (using setModel) instead of trying to update the existing model, I think you'll find it faster and simpler to deal with.

I'd also suggest modelling the row data directly that is rather the adding each property to an array and using that to represent a row, you should add each patient object to the table model, which make up a row. You'll need to use an `AbstractTableModel` instead, but it will make life easier when it comes to editing the data via the table...IMHO